# Android ADB crash - can't debug on device

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, adb, adt

**Device**: Samsung Galaxy Vibrant (i9000)
**SDK**: latest as of 01/12/2011
**OS**: Windows 7 64bit

When I use **eclipse** with the ADT plugin, and try to debug my application, it works for a few times, but after a certain time, when I try to debug my app, ADB stops recognizing my device and what i get is the following (doesn't change even if i reconnect my device):
[snapshot of device chooser http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1024/adby.png](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1024/adby.png)

And after a few minutes, i get an "adb.exe has stopped working!".

I can only debug my app again if I reboot my entire system!
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: It might help you from having to reboot your system: In command line type "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server". This will shutdown and bring back up ADB and, hopefully, resolve the problem (At least temporarily)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work, not even temprorarily... I still get the same device screen

Comment: That sounds pretty bizarre. Do you have access to another phone (even a friends phone for a minute) to see if its the phone itself? Perhaps reinstall the android plugins for eclipse. If that fails maybe try reinstalling eclipse from scratch? Just a few things to try if all else fails

Comment: Do you experience the same issue with an emulator instance?